# Python VideoCapture(0) my camera bad work

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

This my codes :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
# Capture frame-by-frame
ret, frame = cap.read()

# Our operations on the frame come here
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

  # When everything done, release the capture
   cap.release()
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I write the code like this and try to open my camera, but the camera image looks like the screenshot.

Stop working screen shot
[image]

Any idea ? What is the reason?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the right webcam? Do you have more than one in your setup?

Comment: @george.adams1 I'm absolutely sure because c# emgucv works fine

Answer (score 1):

It's indentation problem.
Try this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Provide proper indentation so the program works fine.
Press "q" to stop the program.

Comment: The same problem continues. Have you looked at the screenshot?

Comment: Check your web cam work fine.(inbuilt web cam)

Comment: For usb webcam set "cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)"

Comment: My web cam work wonderful, i tested on c# emgucv. cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1) i tested but problem continues.

Comment: you webcam is inbuilt or usb connected ?

Comment: built-in webcam. laptop